# How do I debug this "Caused by" error?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am a new beginner programmer to android studio, and I need help on as to how I am going to debug the error that I am getting in my fragment. It always stops my app too.

This is what the error is caused by:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.example.marlon.testproject.MainActivity@665ba92 must implement
>   OnFragmentInteractionListener at com.example.marlon.testproject.TestFragment.onAttach(TestFragment.java:84)

And here is the code that it is directing to:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context)
{
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener)
    {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the full stacktrace

Comment: It looks like it's literally throwing the exception you have written in the code, so chances are context probably wasn't an instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener

Comment: @AjitPratapSingh why do you even need it? It's obvious from even this short snippet that `MainActivity` doesn't implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener`

Comment: You need to implement the OnFragmentInteractionListener in Test Fragment

Comment: @MohitSharma no, you need to implement it in `MainActivity`. The `Activity` is the context being passed in `onAttach`. `Fragment` doesn't even extend `Context`

Answer (score 1):

I know stacktraces can seem really scary, but sometimes (as in this time) they're written in nearly plain english.

com.example.marlon.testproject.**MainActivity**@665ba92 **must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener**

Also, that's literally the string you wrote yourself:

> throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
>                   + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");